# Implementing parallel coordinates for multi dimensional data in Java

Tags: java, visualization, data-visualization, jogl, parallel-coordinates

I am planning to implement parallel coordinates in java using JOGL library. Do you have any other suggestions?

Thank you
Bala

Comment: I'm not sure what your mean by parallel coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of 3D engines available in Java. LWJGL is extremely popular, but fairly low level and tailored to games. There are also a number of higher level toolkits, mostly based on LWJGL. JMonkeyEngine is probably the best known and most popular.  Again most are aimed at the games market, and are tailored to it. For example (when I last looked) LWJGL and JMoneyEngine were both restricted to a single viewport per app, which works for games but might not for data visualization.

JOGL is a very thin java wrapper around OpenGL. As such it is incredibly powerful and flexible, but also hard to use and with a steep learning curve. There is also a pure Java package called Java3D, but I know of no successful uses of it and it seems to have fallen out of favor.

You might be interested in [this article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/30/integrating-glpbuffer-and-graphics2d.html) which talks about writing data visualization in JOGL.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [JMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/home/).  It is a little higher level than JOGL.